# Curl is parsing text not xml

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

I am trying to get rate quotes back from a freight carrier.  I am getting the info parsed back to me but in the form of raw data not xml.  I need it in XML so I can parse just once element of the response.  Here is the code i am using:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('Curler.php');

use grafhax\Curler;

$soap = file_get_contents('request.xml');
//print_r($soap);exit;

$user= '******';
$pass= '*******';

$curl = new Curler();
$curl->fail_on_error = 0;
$curl->debug=true;
$curl->SetHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset="utf-8"');

//$curl->PostData('https://webservices.averittexpress.com/LTLRateQuoteService', $soap, false, true,        false, '', "$user:$pass");
//var_dump($curl->response);

//exit;

//$curl->PostData('https://webservices.averittexpress.com/LTLRateQuoteService', $soap, $this-  >lastUrl, true, false, '', "$user:$pass");
$curl->PostData('https://webservices.averittexpress.com/LTLRateQuoteService', $soap);

var_dump($curl->response);
```

Which gives me a response of:

> Library: Curler set header variable: Content-Type=>"text/xml;charset="utf-8"" Library: Curler post request: "https://webservices.averittexpress.com/LTLRateQuoteService" string(3419) "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 17 Nov 2014 16:30:47 GMT X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 Content-Length: 3107 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Language: en-US Set-Cookie: BIGipServerPoolC=84279562.20480.0000; path=/ X-PvInfo: [S10413.C0.A0.R0.G0].[OT/plaintext.OG/documents] 07816643490520RANDLEMANNC27317GREENSBORO SERVICE CENTERMiamiFL33101MIAMI SERVICE CENTER11/17/20142Class 6050037.48 Rated As Class 50.0$187.40[None]0[None]0[None]0[None]0[None]0[None]0[None]0[None]0[None]0[None]0[None]0$125.5667.0900CZARLITE $0.00$17.0757.50$78.91$187.40$187.40500Mon Nov 17 10:30:50 CST 2014"

Answer (score 0):

You have left out the most important part of your code...

```
require_once('Curler.php');
```

^ That included file, which has the class you use later on:

```
$curl = new Curler();
```

^ Which has all the relevant information about how the cURL script is programmed and run.

A lot of the response here is clearly with the opt CURLOPT_HEADER set to true, which is fine for debug, but not really something you are actually interested in.

I actually did a google search for your 'Curler.php', and I found [this](https://github.com/grafhax/php-curler/blob/master/src/Curler.php). It just so happens that the function you're using is forcing the header to be returned, so I was correct in this assumption.

I also did some google searching for Axis2 web server, because that's what the server you linked to said. It would seem they are offering various "objects/functions/methods" you can call on, like

```
https://webservices.averittexpress.com/LTLRateQuoteService.HTTPEndpoint/getCustomerContact
```

^ I don't know if that command is valid, but you probably need to use the correct function/link. If you are using the correct function, then you may need to parse the data yourself. It is very hard for me to guess how the server is programmed. You will have to contact those who set it up or look at their code or api/documentation etc.

Comment: How would I parse the data myself?

Comment: Worst case scenario, you could use regex (PCRE library, which is rather default to have installed and enabled).

Comment: The only function i want to use is there rating function.  With the code I have what would you all recommend to parse the entire XML response from my request?

Comment: @ChrisKennedy http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php